# Why does pgettext_lazy break my template but ugettext_lazy does not?

Tags: django, internationalization, translation, lazy-evaluation

When I use pgettext_lazy to on the help_text of my model, my template fails.  It works fine with ugettext_lazy.

Error

```
Caught TypeError while rendering: Lazy object returned unexpected type.
```

Model

```
class BalanceIncreaseOrder(models.Model):
    amount = models.FloatField(help_text=pgettext_lazy("Translators: please localize this to reflect the correct currency", "Note: amount will be billed in United States dollars (USD)"))
```

Form

```
class BalanceIncreaseOrderForm(ModelFormRequired):
    class Meta:
        model = BalanceIncreaseOrder
        fields = ("amount",)
```

Template

```
{% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
{% endfor %}
```

I've debugged the model just after setting the help text each way.  Both times it prints out

```
<django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x10fcb3a50>
```

Is there a bug in pgettext_lazy?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem. I used

```
unicode(pgettext_lazy('context', 'string'))
```

This will get rid of the error, but now `manage.py makemessages` doesn't pick up the line as translated.

Maybe this will help you though..

EDIT:

Ah, I found a solution:

```
pgettext_lazy(u'context', u'string')
```

This will do the job.

Comment: well... it's the best option I've seen yet.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: something else that may be of interest.  poedit (an app used by many translators to read/edit the po files) does not support the msgctx tag that pgettext creates.  In my case I was incorrectly using the context to provide a comment to the translator.  Instead I just changed it to use the standard inline commenting feature  (# Translators: blah blah blah)

Comment: It seems that it is enough to have only message as unicode pgettext_lazy('context', u'string'))